# Why won't udev create a symlink to /dev/input/by-id for an AT keyboard

Tags: systemd, udev

I have the default systemd `60-persistent-input.rules` file and I have two keyboards one on USB and on a PS2 bus. For the usb devices I get a symlink created in `/dev/input/by-id` with the bus and id. For the PS2 device don't get this.

The device is on `event7`:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=xxxx
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=2000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7
```

but there is no symlink created. Should the udev rules from systemd be creating these?

Comment: I've never seen the default rules create one, but nothing prevents you from modifying the rules so you get one. Technically, the PS/2 keyboard doesn't have an "id", but a name like `/dev/input/by-path/platform-ps2-keyboard` might make sense.

Comment: You'll find it already there under `by-path`, of course, as several `platform-i8042-serio*` entries.  But the question is about `by-id`.

Comment: @JdeBP: My PS/2 keyboard is definitely not in my `by-path` (Devuan), so I assume it depends on the udev-variant ...

Answer (score 0):

PC-compatible keyboards do not have a product identifier.  There is a Read ID command, but the ID it returns is apparently always the same 2-byte value 0xAB, 0x83.  Referring to a keyboard, and the original version with 83 keys.  It sounds like in practice this would be used to double-check that the connected device is a compatible keyboard, as opposed to some other device.  This type of "ID" is not specific enough, in my understanding of the "by-id" concept.

Source: http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/